# Joining of two tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, join

I have two tables which I would like to `join`.

**Tbl_1**

```
RouteNo | StopID | VehicleID | RouteID | VehicleNo | TicketCount | Revenue
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Route_1      0        5           2          DL7S        54         10000
```

**TBL_2**

```
StopID | Stop         | RouteID | VehicleID | Passengers
---------------------------------------------------------
 5       Stop_5         2         5           50
 0       Unknown        2         5           100
 4       Stop_4         2         5           90
```

Now I would like to join two table to get the result like this:

```
Stop      | RouteNo | VehicleNo | TicketCount | Revenue | Passengers
--------------------------------------------------------------------    
Stop_5       Route_1    DL7S         0           0            50
Unknown      Route_1    DL7S         54          10000        100                       
Stop_4       Route_1    DL7S         0           0            90
```

I have tried the following

```
Select 
    a.RouteNo, b.Stop, a.VehicleNo, a.TicketCount, a.Revenue, b.Passengers 
from 
    TBL_1 a
full Join 
    TBL_2 b on a.StopID = b.StopID 
            and a.VehicleID = b.VehicleID 
            and a.RouteID = b.RouteID
```

Actual result:

```
Stop      | RouteNo | VehicleNo | TicketCount | Revenue | Passengers
---------------------------------------------------------------------    
Stop_5       Null       Null         Null          Null       50
Unknown      Route_1    DL7S         54            10000      100                       
Stop_4       Null       Null         Null          Null       90
```

Comment: so did you try with the `or` keyword as I suggested? What is the exact conditions that must be met for the rows to match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `COALESCE`:

```
Select COALESCE(a.RouteNo, b.RouteNo), 
       COALESCE(b.Stop, a.Stop),
       COALESCE(a.VehicleNo, b.VehicleNo),
       COALESCE(a.TicketCount, b..TicketCount),
       COALESCE(a.Revenue, b..Revenue),
       COALESCE(b.Passengers, a.Passengers)
from TBL_1 a
full Join TBL_2 b
on a.StopID = b.StopID and 
   a.VehicleID = b.VehicleID and 
   a.RouteID = b.RouteID
```

Answer (score 1):

Start your query with `TBL_2` instead of `Tbl_1` :

```
Select a.RouteNo, b.Stop, a.VehicleNo, a.TicketCount, a.Revenue, b.Passengers 
from TBL_2 b
Inner Join TBL_1 a
on a.StopID = b.StopID and a.VehicleID = b.VehicleID and a.RouteID = b.RouteID
```

You can also use the `or` keyword in the `on` statement if you need to match your rows if "at least one of the values must match" :

```
Select a.RouteNo, b.Stop, a.VehicleNo, a.TicketCount, a.Revenue, b.Passengers 
from TBL_2 b
Inner Join TBL_1 a
on a.StopID = b.StopID or a.VehicleID = b.VehicleID or a.RouteID = b.RouteID
```

Comment: It will return me only matching rows

Comment: Yes - that is what a JOIN is - matching (or joining) of rows. Please try Select 
    a.RouteNo, b.Stop, a.VehicleNo, a.TicketCount, a.Revenue, b.Passengers 
from 
    TBL_1 a
full Join 
    TBL_2 b on a.StopID = b.StopID

Comment: maybe use the `or` keyword then instead of `and`. What exactly do you want to get ? You didn't specify that.

Comment: Which field are you trying to join (match) on ?

Comment: I don't think you can (in this universe) have OR in the JOIN conditions :)

Comment: Well actually, you can ;) try yourself

Comment: I second the above comment. We can use OR in a join condition